# Deploy war to remote glassfish 3 server

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a war file and I would like to deploy it to remote machine. Both on local and remote machine glassfish 3 is installed and it would be responsible for deploying the app. 
How can I perform remote deploy from one machine to another? Is it possible to do it using asadmin console on one machine and deploy to the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to send ANY commands to a remote Domain Application Server (DAS) from a remote client like asadmin, you must first enable security.  By default, this feature is turned off.  It's simple to fix:

(1) While "on" the remote machine
(2) DAS is running
(3) asadmin enable-secure-admin
(4) asadmin restart-domain

Now you should be able to send asadmin commands from any remote machine.

The change is permanent.  Run the command once and forget it.

For help on the command run this:
asadmin enable-secure-admin --help

Comment: Artem kinda pointed me towards your solution earlier but thx anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

```
asadmin deploy --user admin_user [--password admin_password]
    [--host localhost] [--port 4848] [--passwordfile filename]
    [--secure|-s] [--virtualservers virtual_servers]
    [--type application|ejb|web|connector]
    [--contextroot context_root] [--force=true]
    [--precompilejsp=false]
    [--verify=false] [--name component_name] [--upload=true]
    [--retrieve local_dirpath] [--instance instance_name] filepath
```

Pay attention on --host and --port arguments.
Specify needed host/port and your app will be deployed on remote GF.

Comment: I tried it already but all i get is this:
HTTP connection failed with code 403, message: Remote configuration is currently disabled

Comment: Take a look at a [bug in GF bugtracker](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15886).

Comment: Can you access remotely to the console admin? If yes, you can deploy from there

Comment: I think that setting enable-secure-admin helped me. 
At first nothing changed but I realized that maybe restarting service is required for changes to take effect. After restart it seems to work fine.